# how to count arrays within an array in ruby and return this value

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to count the arrays themselves not the elements. so say i had the following

```
  arrays = [["1 2"],["3 4"],["5 6"],["6 7"]]
```

i am then trying to find a way to return only one of these arrays as a set of instructions if asked for?

Comment: Use `arrays.size`... If this is not what you asked, be specific more please. *as a set of instructions* - means ?

Comment: sorry i am finding it hard to explain. in more depth if i have an array of arrays and each one is a set of instructions, i want to select only one of these arrays within the array how do i do it

Comment: To clarify though i am not trying to add up the amount of elements within the array of arrays. i am trying to select one of the arrays so for example just the first one (1, 2)

Comment: like that `arrays.find { |a| a.first == '1 2' }` or `arrays[index].first` ? `index` means any value `0...array.size`.

Comment: @user3684357 what do you mean by "count (the) arrays"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example showed a multi-dimensional array, which is an array of arrays.

To count the number of arrays in this 2 dimensional array, in other words the number of elements, you could use the following methods.

```
arrays = [["1 2"],["3 4"],["5 6"],["6 7"]]
arrays.length
arrays.size
arrays.count
```

If you would like to return one of them you simply reference the element

```
arrays[0]
=> Returns ["1 2"]
```

If you want to return a random element,

```
arrays.sample
=> Returns a random array
```